# Reusing GWT custom component by making a jar in other project

Tags: gwt

does any one know any nice tutorial for creating a custom component in GWT and using this component as a jar in some other project.

or
Any idea, how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

you have to create a gwt module. Basically you create a gwt project with no / empty entryPoint. When you build it you have to create a jar with the source files. The best option is to use Maven I think. In that case you'll need the gwt maven plugin. This will help you creating the compiled artifact + the source artifact. Here's a typical build phase that I've got in my pom files for such modules.

```xml
 <build>
    <!-- Generate compiled stuff in the folder used for developing mode -->
    <outputDirectory>${webappDirectory}/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <includes>
                            <include>src/main/java</include>
                        </includes>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
                    <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
                    <version>2.3.0</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
                    <artifactId>gwt-dev</artifactId>
                    <version>2.3.0</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <configuration>
                <compileSourcesArtifacts>
                    <compileSourcesArtifact>com.mycompany:myartifact</compileSourcesArtifact>
                    <compileSourcesArtifact>javax.validation:validation-api</compileSourcesArtifact>
                </compileSourcesArtifacts>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>resources</goal>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

In your second project, you have to add the dependency on your new artifact. Thanks to the gwt maven plugin and a bit of configuration, it will be able to pull out the source jar from repository. Here's the pom.xml dependency bit

```xml
   <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
        <artifactId>myartifact</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
```

To get your second project gwt-compiling, you'll need to add a module dependency on the first project. here's the .gwt.xml bit:

```xml
    <inherits name='com.mycompany.gwt-module-i-want-to-import'/>
```

Hope that helps. Give me a shout if you need more info.

Answer (score 1):

GWT needs that the *.java and the *.class be in the classpath, so you just have to package your *.java alongside the *.class in your JAR (or make one JAR with the *.class and another one with the *.java if you prefer).

Other than that it's really as if the code was in the same project (re. gwt.xml and crossing package/module boundaries)

Do you need any more info?

Comment: thanks for reply but i need some more info. I am making a jar file which include a custom widget java file ,its .class file and its gwt.xml file. but when i include this jar file in my other project the project is getting compiled using this jar file but when i see the GWT generated link in browser , i get the error as "Import can not be resolved". please help me out of this.